# Change dimensions of image but only declare width

Tags: php, image

I have this code:

```
<?php
// The file
$filename = 'http://www.tagesschau.de/multimedia/bilder/feinstaub-messstation-101.jpg';
$new_width = 400;
$new_height = 200;

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
?>
```

When calling this script it'll show the image `http://www.tagesschau.de/multimedia/bilder/feinstaub-messstation-101.jpg` but resize the image before: 400 x 200.

You can declare width and height with the values in `$new_width` and `$new_height`. I need to specify width and height.

What I want to reach: I want to only declare width. Height should adapt dynamically proportional to the original dimensions. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `$newHeight = $newWidth / ($oldWidth / $oldHeight);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the ratio of new to original width, then apply that factor to height:

```
$factor = $new_width / $width;
$new_height = $height * $factor;
```